# Loading a kernel module at run time using "compatible" property of device node in device-tree

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, devices, device-tree

If I know the "compatible" property string of a device(from the device tree), can I use it at runtime to load the corresponding kernel driver module? I do not have access to the driver source. I am using a linux kernel. Thanks!